# javascript loop through API response json data

Tags: javascript, node-red

I am learning javascript trying to incorporate some code that will go inside a Node Red function block. In the code below `var data` is the json payload from an API.

```
var data = {
            "201201/tempUoTwoBalco": 
                {"value": 63.1199951171875, "route": "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/tempUoTwoBalco", "writable": false}, 
            "201201/tempUoThreeBalco": 
                {"value": 74.12999725341797, "route": "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/tempUoThreeBalco", "writable": false}, 
            "201201/Oat": 
                {"value": 89.99999237060547, "route": "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/Oat", "writable": false}, 
            "201201/RmTmpSpt": 
                {"value": 79.99999237060547, "route": "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/RmTmpSpt", "writable": true}, 
            "201201/RmTmp": 
                {"value": NaN, "route": "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/RmTmp", "writable": false}, 
            "201201/UhCmd": 
                {"value": 0, "route": "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/UhCmd", "writable": false}, 
            "201201/GlblHtgDsbl": 
                {"value": 0, "route": "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/GlblHtgDsbl", "writable": false}
};

console.log(data)


var supplyTemp = {};
var returnTemp = {};

sensor1 = "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/tempUoTwoBalco"
sensor2 = "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/tempUoThreeBalco"



for(var key in data){
    for(var key1 in data[key]){
        if(key1 === sensor1){
            console.log("sensor1 found "+ data[key][key1])
            // append float to supplyTemp?
        };

        if(key1 === sensor2){
            console.log("sensor2 found "+ data[key][key1])
            // append float to returnTemp?
        };
    };
};
```

How could I incorporate the for loop `for(var key in data){` into a function that returns `supplyTemp` and `returnTemp` if the `keys` are found in the json payload? Something like `return [[supplyTemp,returnTemp]];`

Thanks for any javascript wisdom, this is something I am trying to gain...

Comment: what do you mean by _append float to supplyTemp_? could you provide an example of your desired result.

Comment: It looks like supplyTemp and returnTemp are possible values of `route` property, rather than being object keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `value` properties of matching `sensor1` and `sensor2` to be stored in `supplyTemp` and `returnTemp` respectively? You can use `filter` to filter the values that are matching the provided sensors, and then map the results to fetch values. Here's an example:

```js
var data = {
  "201201/tempUoTwoBalco":
    { "value": 63.1199951171875, "route": "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/tempUoTwoBalco", "writable": false },
  "201201/tempUoThreeBalco":
    { "value": 74.12999725341797, "route": "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/tempUoThreeBalco", "writable": false },
  "201201/Oat":
    { "value": 89.99999237060547, "route": "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/Oat", "writable": false },
  "201201/RmTmpSpt":
    { "value": 79.99999237060547, "route": "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/RmTmpSpt", "writable": true },
  "201201/RmTmp":
    { "value": NaN, "route": "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/RmTmp", "writable": false },
  "201201/UhCmd":
    { "value": 0, "route": "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/UhCmd", "writable": false },
  "201201/GlblHtgDsbl":
    { "value": 0, "route": "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/GlblHtgDsbl", "writable": false }
};

var supplyTemp = {};
var returnTemp = {};

let sensor1 = "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/tempUoTwoBalco"
let sensor2 = "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/tempUoThreeBalco"

supplyTemp = (Object.values(data).filter(element => element.route == sensor1).map(result => result.value))
returnTemp = (Object.values(data).filter(element => element.route == sensor2).map(result => result.value))

console.log([supplyTemp, returnTemp])
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method which returns the value of the object you find.
My code is very similar to @deepak except it's D.R.Y. (Don't repeat yourself).

I opted for `.find()` over `.filter()` as your code suggests the sensors are unique.

- Find will either; return the matching item or null.
- Filter will return an array of matching items or an empty array.

You should choose whichever one you prefer.

```
let data = {
            "201201/tempUoTwoBalco": 
                {"value": 63.1199951171875, "route": "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/tempUoTwoBalco", "writable": false}, 
            "201201/tempUoThreeBalco": 
                {"value": 74.12999725341797, "route": "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/tempUoThreeBalco", "writable": false}, 
            "201201/Oat": 
                {"value": 89.99999237060547, "route": "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/Oat", "writable": false}, 
            "201201/RmTmpSpt": 
                {"value": 79.99999237060547, "route": "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/RmTmpSpt", "writable": true}, 
            "201201/RmTmp": 
                {"value": NaN, "route": "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/RmTmp", "writable": false}, 
            "201201/UhCmd": 
                {"value": 0, "route": "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/UhCmd", "writable": false}, 
            "201201/GlblHtgDsbl": 
                {"value": 0, "route": "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/GlblHtgDsbl", "writable": false}
};


let supplyTemp = {};
let returnTemp = {};

let sensor1 = "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/tempUoTwoBalco";
let sensor2 = "/vui/platforms/benshome/devices/201201/tempUoThreeBalco";

console.log(getTemp(sensor1, data));
// returns 63.1199951171875

console.log(getTemp(sensor1, data));
// returns 63.1199951171875

console.log(getTemp('', data));
// returns null

/**
* Get the sensor value for the given sensorRoute in the given array.
*/
function getTemp(sensorRoute, arr) { 
    let foundItem = Object.values(arr).find(element => element.route == sensorRoute);

  return foundItem ? foundItem.value : null;
}
```